# Change color of breakpoint mark background in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, color-scheme

I know i can change colors like `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> ...`.
However i cant find option to change color of that line. Its the place where breakpoint red mark appears. I want to make it grey like other parts of my scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Indicator Margin`